# Exercise about spectrum of selfadjoint operator.

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, spectral-theory

I'm stuck on an exercise about the spectrum of a selfadjoint operator on a Hilbert space.

The problem is the following:

Let $(X,\langle \cdot, \cdot\rangle)$ a Hilbert space and let $A \in B(H)$ a selfadjoint operator such that $\langle Ax,x \rangle \geq 0$ for every $x \in X$.

a) If $m=\inf_{\|x\|=1}\langle Ax,x \rangle$, prove that $\lambda<m \Rightarrow \lambda \in \rho(A)$.

b) If $M=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\langle Ax,x \rangle$, show that $\sigma(A) \subseteq [m,M]$

any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $N=\{ (Ax,x) : \|x\|=1\}$. Suppose $\lambda \notin N^c$ (closure of $N$) so that there exists $\delta$ such that the following holds whenever $\|x\|=1$:
$$
         0 < \delta \le |(Ax,x)-\lambda|=|((A-\lambda I)x,x)|\le \|(A-\lambda I)x\|\|x\| =
                \|(A-\lambda I)x\|
$$
Then $\|(A-\lambda I)x\| \ge \delta \|x\|$ for all $x$. (The same holds for $\overline{\lambda}$ as well.) Use this to argue that
$$
     \{ \lambda \in\mathbb{C} : \mbox{dist}(\lambda,N) > 0\} \subseteq\rho(A) \implies
        \sigma(A)\subseteq N^{c}.
$$

Comment: Do you mean $\lambda \notin N$, right?

Comment: Well there is the characterization of the Injectives operators with closed range that is just $\|(A-\lambda I)x\| \geq \delta\|x\|$. Then $(A-\lambda I)$ is injective. To show that $\lambda$ is in the resolvent I have to show that $(A-\lambda I)$ is a surjective operator. And now I'm stuck again!

Comment: Ok I have the surjection because $A$ is selfadjoint and has no residual spectrum. For completing the part b) I have to show that $\sup_{\|x\|=1} \langle Ax, x \rangle = \|A\|$. Uhmmm

Comment: A bit late, but why does such a $\delta$ exist? (I don't see why $N$ is closed?)

Comment: @ougoah : I started by assuming $\lambda\notin N^c$ where $N^c$ is the closure of the numerical range $N$. That gives the existence of $\delta > 0$.

Comment: Ahh thanks, I mistook that for the complement of N. Cheers

Comment: @ougoah : Thanks for pointing out the confusion. I made a parenthetical remark in case someone else sees this answer. It's good to keep the site clean if possible.